# Spring security @PostFilter in combination with maxResults

Tags: java, spring-security, acl

I am using Spring security for my web services. I'm using annotations to specify the security conditions. Right now I'm facing the following problem. Consider the following service method:

```
@Override
@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read')")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<UserDTO> listUsers(int firstResult, int maxResults, String orderBy, boolean ascending) {

//Retrieve users and put them in a collection
}
```

Post filtering works after the method is invoked, but the contract of the method is to return a collection of size #maxResults if at least that many users exist. How do I achieve this, because objects may be filtered out after the method has been invoked. Of course I could revert to manual access checking inside the method, but I thought that there maybe would be a more elegant way of doing this.